# How do you limit the amount of posts shown in a while loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

So, I've been looking all over and tried different methods, but I can't seem to get to limit a number of posts shown. Can anyone help?

```
<?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="portfolio-item <?php the_field('category'); ?> <?php the_field('thumbnail_size'); ?>">
  <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <div class="portfolio-img-wrap" data-background="<?php the_field('image'); ?>"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-overlay"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-caption">
      <h6 class="portfolio-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h6><span class="portfolio-subtitle"><?php the_field('category'); ?></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="portfolio-link" href="portfolio-single.html"></a>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: use post_per_page = 10 in your wp_query @Alexander Nicholas

Comment: You need to check this. It is very similar to your question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181541/how-to-limit-the-number-of-posts-that-wp-query-gets

Comment: Use this arguement in your post array 
$args = array('posts_per_page'         => 'Your_limit')

Answer (score 0):

set a if statement its not so hard:)
then just save then info in get when to start and when to break then u have it:D

Answer (score 0):

> You could add a count variable and break out of loop when you want. 
>   See the code below

```
$count = 0;
<?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
$count++;
<div class="portfolio-item <?php the_field('category'); ?> <?php the_field('thumbnail_size'); ?>">
  <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
    <div class="portfolio-img-wrap" data-background="<?php the_field('image'); ?>"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-overlay"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-caption">
      <h6 class="portfolio-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h6><span class="portfolio-subtitle"><?php the_field('category'); ?></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="portfolio-link" href="portfolio-single.html"></a>
</div>
if($count == 10){
break;
}

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Nice but the wordpress query provides the option to limit the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Her is something clearly wrong.

A while loop shows all results that you got. If you want to limit that you should change the statement that fetches the posts not the while loop.

Otherwise you will fetch x posts and only output for example 10 ... That is an performance factor.

If you want to change the fetch result you have to modify the wp query (as others mentioned).

But in your example there is no custom query. Its the default one... So you can change the amount of posts per page in your backend under settings. Otherwise you should use a custom query and not the default one:

```
$myposts = get_posts( array( 'showposts'=>10 ) );

if( $myposts ):

    global $post; foreach( $myposts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );

        // Your output like the_title() etc

    endforeach:

endif;
```